# How to connect multiple accounts to contract in hardhat staging test?

Tags: solidity, javascript, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I am writing a staging test on goerli testnet for a multi-sig contract. I'm trying to test proposing a transaction, having all 3 owners confirm the transaction, and then any one of the owners execute it.

But I am confused about how to connect different accounts to the contract.

I added multiple private keys in my `accounts` section inside my `hardhat.config.js` and inside my staging tests I called `getNamedAccounts()` to use them, but `multiSig.connect(owner2).confirmTransaction(0)` returns me a voidSigner error.

Here is my staging test so far:

```js
developmentChains.includes(network.name)
    ? describe.skip
    : describe("multi sig staging test", function () {
        let multiSig, chainId, user
          beforeEach(async function () {
              chainId = network.config.chainId              
              multiSig = await ethers.getContract("MultiSig")  
              //console.log(`multiSig address: ${multiSig.address}`)   
              user = "0xEC6Cb786Fd27BA1A79809A88A44d3b9A2b06992A"
          })
          it("allows owners to propose and execute transactions that have set number of confirmations", async function () {
            const {deployer, owner2, owner3} = await getNamedAccounts()
            // console.log(`deployer address: ${deployer}`)
            // console.log(`owner2 address: ${owner2}`)
            // console.log(`owner3 address: ${owner3}`)
            await multiSig.proposeTransaction(user, 7, "0x")
            await multiSig.connect(owner2).confirmTransaction(0)
          })
      })
```

And here is the error code:

`Error: VoidSigner cannot sign transactions (operation="signTransaction", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=abstract-signer/5.7.0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `getNamedAccounts()` use the ethers.js method `getSigners()`
This grabs the accounts from your hardhat.config.js on whatever network you are on.

`const [deployer, owner2, owner3] = await ethers.getSigners()`